# fsolve anonymous function with two inputs

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
Eq = @(x1, x2) [x1-6, x2+3];
fsolve(Eq, [4 1])
```

but get the following error:

```
??? Input argument "x2" is undefined.

Error in ==> @(x1,x2)[x1-6,x2+3]


Error in ==> fsolve at 193
    fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in ==> Untitled at 6
fsolve(Eq, [4, 1])
```

It works perfectly when I change the function to a one input function.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing in the vector [4 1] as the `x1` argument.

Do this instead:

```
Eq = @(x) [x(1)-6, x(2)+3];
fsolve(Eq, [4 1])
```

The `fsolve` expects a function with one argument (either a vector or matrix), therefore a function with two arguments won't work.

Comment: any way to do it without changing my equation?

Comment: Well, you could write another function `g = @(z) Eq(z(1),z(2))` and do `fsolve(g,[4 1])`. But ultimately, you have got to pass a single-argument function to `fsolve`.